# ie6 shadow issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Demo: http://jsbin.com/esupex/2

i have shadow on the box and its making the div go on the new line and if i remove the shadow, the div goes back on the same line. following are the screenshots.

ie6 shadow break-line error - [full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T3iw.png):
[image]

ie6 no shadow (this is just to show what it looks like after no shadow, but we do need shadow) - [full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsPKb.png):
[image]

final layout should look like this. this screenshot is from firefox - [full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icHjX.png):
[image]

following is the line that is causing the issue and i dont know how to solve it:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=140, Color='#eeeeee');
```

Comment: Do you really have to support ie6? _Really?_

Comment: yes, my complete application supports ie6, just this small issue is the problem left so far.

Comment: I'd say that if it's causing an issue in IE6, then just remove it from that browser.

Comment: no, cant do that, need it. its in many places and layout would'nt look nice without it. plus cant just run away from the issues or find it easy way by removing it, have to solve them and teach others about it.

Comment: I agree with @Kyle - there's nothing wrong with letting old (or in this case ancient) browsers fall back to simpler solutions, like a simple gray border. People with IE6 won't know that they are missing a shadow, and if anyone asks, you can tell them the truth: IE6 does not support a lot of web standards, including box-shadow. It's called progressive enhancement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative margin to the box being rendered too low if you MUST have a shadow in IE.

http://jsbin.com/esupex/36

I added modified the to be:

```
#playerNavBox {
  height:36px;
  margin-right: 260px;
  *margin-top: -43px;
}
```

Comment: this is perfect, better then width and right margin. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with a fixed or fluid layout? The problem is the most right div cannot position itself next to the left one. Give the left one a float left and a fixed width in px or % and all should be fine.

If your layout is fluid: note that borders, shadow, margin and padding in px do not play well with % and should never ever be on the same elements

Also, in IE6 if you give an element a float and on the same side a padding or margin, it will be double the margin/padding you specified. like described here:

http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-double-margin-padding-ie6-css-float

For IE6 you could use a border instead of a shadow to get more or less the same look.

Comment: its fluid layout. well if you click on the example link and run it on the ie6, you will see the error and if you just remove the shadow line from css, then it will work fine.

Comment: For IE6 you could use a border instead of a shadow to get more or less the same look. Had a good look at it, but it seems IE6 makes the shadow way larger then you define it to be.

Comment: Thats my solution for IE6 atleast, never design for it but make it look acceptable afterwards. Cant really ignore it as all the people above state, still 10% of all global pageviews is done with ie6. To not support it would be rediculous.

Comment: check the answer if its proper way to do it, but it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

reducing the margin and defining the width fixes the problem.

old css:

```
#playerNavBox {
        height:36px;
        margin-right: 260px;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
```

new css:

```
#playerNavBox {
    height:36px;
    margin-right: 260px;
    background-color:#fff;
    /* ie6 shadow fix */
    *width:81%;
    *margin-right: 250px;
}
```

Comment: this will give you issues tough when changing resolutions, combining px size and % size never works well

Comment: ya you are right about that. just thinking what else way i can do, without removing the shadow. anyone!?